# Gulp command not found after install

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, npm, gulp

I installed gulp(globally) and it looks like it worked because it ran this code:

```
├── tildify@0.2.0
├── interpret@0.3.5
├── pretty-hrtime@0.2.1
├── deprecated@0.0.1
├── archy@0.0.2
├── minimist@0.2.0
├── semver@2.3.2
├── orchestrator@0.3.7 (stream-consume@0.1.0, sequencify@0.0.7, end-of-stream@0.1.5)
├── chalk@0.5.1 (escape-string-regexp@1.0.1, ansi-styles@1.1.0, supports-color@0.2.0, strip-ansi@0.3.0, has-ansi@0.1.0)
├── gulp-util@2.2.20 (lodash._reinterpolate@2.4.1, dateformat@1.0.8-1.2.3, vinyl@0.2.3, through2@0.5.1, multipipe@0.1.1, lodash.template@2.4.1)
├── liftoff@0.12.0 (extend@1.2.1, minimist@0.1.0, resolve@0.7.4, findup-sync@0.1.3)
└── vinyl-fs@0.3.5 (graceful-fs@3.0.2, lodash@2.4.1, mkdirp@0.5.0, strip-bom@0.3.1, vinyl@0.2.3, through2@0.5.1, glob-watcher@0.0.6, glob-stream@3.1.14)
```

But when I type `gulp` it says `-bash: gulp: command not found`

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Mr_Green meant:  sudo npm install gulp -g

Answer (score 181, accepted):

Turns out that npm was installed in the wrong directory so I had to change the “npm config prefix” by running this code:

```
npm config set prefix /usr/local
```

Then I reinstalled gulp globally (with the -g param) and it worked properly.

This article is where I found the solution: http://webbb.be/blog/command-not-found-node-npm

Comment: Thanks, this worked. So weird. I installed it on macbook 1, it works, macbook 2, doesnt work, so i have to do this. Crazy.

Comment: how to do this on windows?

Comment: Works amazingly thanks! 

PS: for people reading this with post macos montery: the terminal has changed to zsh, not bash, to switch it back, run "chsh -s /bin/bash" and then restart your terminal, should work then

Answer (score 64):

Not sure why the question was down-voted, but I had the same issue and following the blog post recommended solve the issue. One thing I should add is that in my case, once I ran:

```
npm config set prefix /usr/local
```

I confirmed the `npm root -g` was pointing to `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm`, but in order to install `gulp` in `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`, I had to use `sudo`:

`sudo npm install gulp -g`

Comment: I was searching for this solution! THANK YOU!
Command: `npm config set prefix /usr/local` SOLVED problem!

Answer (score 23):

If you're using `tcsh` (which is my default shell on Mac OS X), you probably just need to type `rehash` into the shell just after the install completes:

```
npm install -g gulp
```

followed immediately by:

```
rehash
```

Otherwise, if this is your very first time installing `gulp`, your shell may not recognize that there's a new executable installed -- so you either need to start a new shell, or type `rehash` in the current shell.

(This is basically a one-time thing for each command you install globally.)

Answer (score 17):

I realize that this is an old thread, but for Future-Me, and posterity, I figured I should add my two-cents around the "running npm as sudo" discussion. *Disclaimer: I do not use Windows. These steps have only been proven on non-windows machines, both virtual and physical.*

You can avoid the need to use sudo by changing the permission to npm's default directory.

---

### How to: change permissions in order to run npm without `sudo`

#### Step 1: Find out where npm's default directory is.

- To do this, open your terminal and run:
  `npm config get prefix`

#### Step 2: Proceed, based on the output of that command:

- **Scenario One:** npm's default directory is `/usr/local`
  *For most users, your output will show that npm's default directory is /usr/local, in which case you can skip to step 4 to update the permissions for the directory.*
- **Scenario Two:** npm's default directory is `/usr` or `/Users/YOURUSERNAME/node_modules` or `/Something/Else/FishyLooking`
  *If you find that npm's default directory is not /usr/local, but is instead something you can't explain or looks fishy, you should go to step 3 to change the default directory for npm, or **you risk messing up your permissions** on a much larger scale.*

#### Step 3: Change npm's default directory:

- There are a couple of ways to go about this, including creating a directory specifically for global installations and then adding that directory to your $PATH, but since /usr/local is probably already in your path, I think it's simpler to just change npm's default directory to that. Like so:  `npm config set prefix /usr/local`

  - For more info on the other approaches I mentioned, see the npm docs [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions).

#### Step 4: Update the permissions on npm's default directory:

- Once you've verified that npm's default directory is in a sensible location, you can update the permissions on it using the command:
  `sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(npm config get prefix)/{lib/node_modules,bin,share}`

---

Now you should be able to run `npm <whatever>` without `sudo`. *Note: You may need to restart your terminal in order for these changes to take effect.*

Answer (score 8):

I had similar problem I did the following steps and it worked.Go to mac terminal and execute the commands,

1.npm config set prefix /usr/local

2.sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(npm config get prefix)/{lib/node_modules,bin,share}

This two commands will set the npm path right and you no longer have to use sudo in npm.
Next uninstall the gulp

3. npm uninstall gulp
4. Installl gulp again without sudo,
   npm install gulp -g

This should work!!

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem with getting "command not found" after install but I was installed into /usr/local as described in the solution above.

My problem seemed to be caused by me running the install with sudo. I did the following.

1. Removing gulp again with sudo
2. Changing the owner of /usr/local/lib/node_modules to my user
3. Installing gulp again without sudo. "npm install gulp -g"

Comment: It seems more sensible that I don't need to install anything locally with sudo and why should I ever need to use sudo - for me when I start using sudo then things break when you don't run the command line as sudo - like in day to day dev under user. 
I tend to think your way is much more correct - sudo is not always the best answer though it seems to fix for the moment.

Answer (score 4):

If you are on Mac **run use root privilege**

`sudo npm install gulp-cli --global`

To check if it's installed run

```
gulp -v
```

CLI version: 2.2.0 (The output)

> Local version:  Unknown

Answer (score 3):

You need to do this `npm install --global gulp`. It works for me and i also had this problem. It because you didn't install globally this package.

Answer (score 1):

I got this working on Win10 using a combination of the answers from above and elsewhere. Posting here for others and future me.

I followed the instructions from here: https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/quick-start but on the last step after typing   gulp --version   I got the message   -bash: gulp: command not found

To fix this:

1. I added %AppData%\npm to my Path environment variable
2. Closed all gitbash (cmd, powershell, etc...) and restarted gitbash.
3. Then gulp --version worked

Also, found the below for reasons why not to install gulp globally and how to remove it (not sure if this is advisable though):

[what does gulp-"cli" stands for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35571679/what-does-gulp-cli-stands-for)

[How to uninstall Gulp CLI from NPM globally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53953770/how-to-uninstall-gulp-cli-from-npm-globally)

Answer (score 0):

In my case adding **sudo** before npm install solved *gulp command not found* problem

`sudo npm install`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to leave your prefix intact, just export it's bin dir to your PATH variable:
`export PATH=$HOME/your-path/bin:$PATH`
I added this line to my $HOME/.profile and sourced it.

Setting prefix to `/usr/local` makes you use `sudo`, so I like to have it in my user dir. You can check your prefix with `npm prefix -g`.

Answer (score 0):

Behind corporate proxies the global command usually doesnt work , hence u can run the command where the gulp is installed locally.