# what does gulp-"cli" stands for?

Tags: gulp, task, runner

Can someone please explain what exactly are the differences between the following two methods of gulp installation:

```
$ npm install --global gulp-cli
```

and

```
$ sudo npm install -g gulp
```

It looks to me that both do the same thing except that the first method gives me a version 1.2.1, and the later gives me version 3.9.1

Can someone put into simple terms what exactly are the differences? and plus what is "cli" stands for?

Comment: CLI presumably is an abbreviation for command-line interface (as opposed to GUI = graphical user interface).

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The goal of gulp-cli is to let you use gulp like a global program, but without installing gulp globally.

For example if you installed gulp 3.9.1 globally and your project testGulp4 has gulp 4.0 installed locally, what would happen if you run `gulp -v` into testGulp4?

- Without gulp-cli globally installed :

  ```
  CLI version 3.9.1
  ```

  In this case the version displayed is the global version of gulp. The local version 4.0 is totally ignored.
- With gulp-cli globally installed :

  ```
  CLI version 1.2.1
  Local version 4.0.0-alpha.2
  ```

  In this case the version displayed is the global version of gulp-cli and the local version of gulp. The global gulp 3.9.1 is totally ignored.

**Conclusion** :

- gulp-cli: is preferred because it allows you to use different versions of gulp.
- gulp: needs a local version of gulp installed.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! :)

Answer (score 24):

CLI stands for Command Line Interface.

`gulp` is a JavaScript library. It lets you use gulp from JavaScript code.

`gulp-cli` is a utility program that lets you access gulp from your shell.

Comment: so for using gulp we need to install it globally , or will it work locally as well ?

Comment: @ramasCoder — These days you should install it non-globally and use `npx` to run it.