# When performing a global install of Gulp, should you install "gulp" or "gulp-cli"?

Tags: macos, npm, gulp

The Gulp github page says to run

```
    npm install --global gulp-cli
```

but nearly every tutorial I've come across says to run

```
    npm install -g gulp
```

Is there any substantial difference between the two options?

Comment: [Here's the same question with some great answers.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35571679/what-does-gulp-cli-stands-for)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are two different modules, `gulp` is intended to be installed locally for the project, and `gulp-cli` globally, this allows you to use different versions of gulp for different projects.

It's mostly a legacy thing, in the past there were no `gulp-cli`. The gulp team got more knowledge and decided to split it up.

It's recommended to use `gulp-cli` globally, and `gulp` locally.

And the [Getting Started](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md) documentation also prompts you, to delete any globally installed `gulp` module.

There is no difference between `--global` and `-g` the latter is just a shorthand flag.