# How to uninstall Gulp CLI from NPM globally?

Tags: npm

I have the following package installed globally via npm:

```
+-- gulp-cli@2.0.1 (github:gulpjs/gulp-cli#4782b9a582ce7cc7e009073705a565b57d235332)
```

I have tried to uninstall it like so...

```
npm uninstall gulp-cli@2.0.1
```

But it does not remove it.  How can I get this package removed from my global location?

I'm on npm version 6.1.0

Comment: add the -g flag. Here is an example https://docs.npmjs.com/uninstalling-packages-and-dependencies#unscoped-package-2

Comment: i did, it does not work. when i list all global packages after attempting to remove it, that same package is still listed.

Comment: Can you post the exact command you used and the npm version?

Comment: I posted my npm version above

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to **R. Wanjohi** I figured it out for my machine. I had to do the following to get the global version of gulp cli off my machine:

```
npm rm -g gulp-cli
```

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing the same problem but when I used the following code, it worked:

```
npm rm -g gulp
```

Answer (score 2):

it's pretty simple, to uninstall a global package run

```
npm uninstall -g <package-name>
```

to verify run

```
npm ls -g --depth=0
```

for short [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XbvjZxUZJGg)

Answer (score 1):

You need to uninstall it globally (add the `-g` tag)

```
npm uninstall -g gulp-cli@2.0.1
```

Here is the npm docs: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/uninstall.html

Comment: I wish you were right.  But, the package still gets listed after attempting to do this exact thing.

Comment: Do you have an inform message when you uninstall the package (me is `removed 318 packages in 6.252s`)? And yet how do you know your package is still there?

Comment: It just says __up to date in 0.042s__.  And I know because when I run __npm list -g --depth=0__ it shows it listed.  This is crazy.